# Prevent body from scrolling (mobile, native browsers)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

On native browser of Samsung Galaxy S5 / S6, following piece of CSS:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

doesn't stop the body from scrolling.

Is there a workaround for this?

Edit: as discussed below, this can be done by adding overflow:hidden to html tag as well. But this introduces an issue where window scrolls to top.

**Is it possible to prevent body from scrolling without the scroll side effect (page scrolling to top once html, body get overflow:hidden)?**

Side note: issue is reproducible in following environments:

```
Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 5.0) Browser: Native;
Samsung Galaxy S6 (Android 6.0.1) Browser: Native;
iPhone 5S (iOS 8.4.1) Browsers: Chrome; Safari;
iPhone 6+ (iOS 9.3.2) Browsers: Chrome; Safari;
```

Answer (score 5):

try

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: It works on desktop browsers, and it works on chrome mobile, don't know about the others.

Answer (score 1):

## Css + Javascript solution:

css class to disable scrolling

```
.lock-scroll{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

javascript code to fix the scrollTop jump after applying the css class:

```
function disableScroll(elem){
    var lastScrollTop = $(elem).scrollTop();
    $(elem).addClass("lock-scroll");
    $(elem).css("top", "-" + lastScrollTop + "px");
}

function enableScroll(elem){
    var lastScrollTop = Number($('#wmd-input-39380954').css("top").match(/[0-9]/g).join(""));
    $(elem).removeClass("lock-scroll");
    $(elem).css("top", "0px");
    $(elem).scrollTop(lastScrollTop);
}
```

## Disable scroll by target element

***index.html:***

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <style>
            body{
                  background-color:#333333;
                  color: white;
              }
              #modalView{
                  position: fixed;
                  width: 100%;
                  height: 100%;
                  left: 0;
                  top: 0;
                  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
                  overflow: scroll;
              }
              #modalViewScroll{
                width: 300px;
                height: 200px;
                overflow: scroll;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                top: 0;
                margin: auto;
                background: white;
                color: red;
              }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        BODY SCROLL 1<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 2<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 3<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 4<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 5<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 6<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 7<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 8<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 9<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 1<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 2<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 3<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 4<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 5<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 6<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 7<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 8<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 9<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 1<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 2<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 3<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 4<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 5<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 6<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 7<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 8<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 9<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 1<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 2<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 3<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 4<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 5<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 6<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 7<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 8<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 9<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 1<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 2<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 3<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 4<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 5<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 6<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 7<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 8<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 9<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 1<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 2<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 3<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 4<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 5<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 6<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 7<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 8<br/>_____________<br/>BODY SCROLL 9<br/>_____________<br/>
        <div id="modalView">
            <div id="modalViewScroll">
                MODAALLLL SCROLL 1<br/>__________________<br/>MODAALLLL SCROLL 2<br/>__________________<br/>MODAALLLL SCROLL 3<br/>__________________<br/>MODAALLLL SCROLL 4<br/>__________________<br/>MODAALLLL SCROLL 5<br/>__________________<br/>MODAALLLL SCROLL 6<br/>__________________<br/>MODAALLLL SCROLL 7<br/>__________________<br/>MODAALLLL SCROLL 8<br/>__________________<br/>MODAALLLL SCROLL 9<br/>__________________<br/>MODAALLLL SCROLL 1<br/>__________________<br/>MODAALLLL SCROLL 2<br/>__________________<br/>MODAALLLL SCROLL 3<br/>__________________<br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function scrollDisabled(e){
                    // Two option :
                    // 
                    // 1) scroll anywhere will scroll the modal but you have to handle scroll state, and disable scroll with close modal
                    // 
                    // if(scrollingModal){
                    //   $('#modalViewScroll').scrollTop($('#modalViewScroll').scrollTop() + e.deltaY);
                    //   return true;
                    // }

                    // 2) scroll only above the modal 
                    if (e.target.id == "modalViewScroll") {
                      $('#modalViewScroll').scrollTop($('#modalViewScroll').scrollTop() + e.deltaY);
                      return true;
                    }
                }

                function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
                  if(scrollDisabled(e)){
                    var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};
                    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
                        preventDefault(e);
                        return false;
                    }
                  }
                }

                function preventDefault(e) {
                  if(scrollDisabled(e)){
                    e = e || window.event;
                    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
                    e.returnValue = false;
                  }
                }
                function hookScroll() {
                    if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
                        window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
                    window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
                    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
                    window.ontouchmove = preventDefault; // mobile
                    document.onkeydown = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
                }
                hookScroll();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

## To avoid scrolling to top with click event fires

You must add `return false;` after the click event;

#### Example:

```
<button onclick="openModal(); return false;">Open Modal</button>
```

## To disable scroll in mobile browsers

You need to set `overflow:hidden` also for the `<html>` tag.

#### Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html,body{overflow:hidden}
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        // You html body
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I add overflow:hidden to html, window scrolls to top. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: you can add you scroll div inside the body and handle the scroll top

Comment: Can you post an example of what you want ? I'm familiar with this issues.

Comment: When I add html: overflow:hidden (modal opened), my background (body) scrolls to top. I'd like to know if I can avoid the scrolling side effect.

Comment: I guess you opened the modal with onclick event right?

Comment: Simply adding overflow: hidden to html tag scrolls the body to top, not a click event. You can try it yourself. I am beginning to think this is as best as it can get (with scroll issue).

Comment: You can disable scroll without adding `overflow:hidden`

Comment: I am aware that we can override scroll events, but that won't work for me as I need the scroll inside modal dialog.

Comment: when you override the scroll events you can check the target element

Comment: See the last edit, I added two options to handle the scroll event

Comment: I have added new solution on how to do it without hook the scroll listeners

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply do with this boostrap `modal pop up` , just copy paste with this to a html page

```css
body {
 width:100%;
 height:1000px;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>disable body scroll</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

</head>

<body>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the trick is to make the BODY position relative so that it does not scroll to the top when you set it:

```
BODY {    
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything and finally figured it out I think.

Place the following into your body:

```
body {
   overflow: hidden;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

This works. It seems that certain browsers ignore overflow but recognise the individual -x and -y values, but those alone aren't enough. Using the position fixed method with all 4 directions set to zero makes it all work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `margin:0px !important` on body element

Comment: Any idea how this helps? Why zero, why important?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the npm package [body-scroll-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-scroll-lock).

Basically combines a CS and JS solution so that it works across iOS and other devices, as well as desktop browsers. Does NOT use `position: fixed`!

Essentially, it locks body scroll while maintaining scroll of a target element. Source code can be found on the [Github](https://github.com/willmcpo/body-scroll-lock/blob/master/src/bodyScrollLock.js) repo.

Here's a [demo](http://wp-os.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/body-scroll-lock-demo/index.html).